# Get actual numbers instead of normalized value in seaborn KDE plots

Tags: python, scipy, seaborn, kernel-density

I have three dataframes and I plot the KDE using seaborn module in python. The issue is that these plots try to make the area under the curve 1 (which is how they are intended to perform), so the height in the plots are normalized ones. But is there any way to show the actual values instead of the normalized ones. Also is there any way I can find out the point of intersection for the curves?

Note: I do not want to use the curve_fit method of scipy as I am not sure about the distribution I will get for each dataframe, it can be multimodal also.

```
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure()
sns.distplot(data_1['gap'],kde=True,hist=False,label='1')
sns.distplot(data_2['gap'],kde=True,hist=False,label='2')
sns.distplot(data_3['gap'],kde=True,hist=False,label='3')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Output for the code is attached in the link as I can't post images.[plot_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSBir.png)

Comment: What does "actual values" mean in this context?

Comment: @mwaskom The actual value here means the frequency of the value. But the curve should be smooth, it means if the frequency of a value is 0 but the frequency for values before and after of the current value are high there shouldn't be a trough.

Answer (score -1):

You can just grab the line and rescale its y-values with `set_data`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# create some data
n = 1000
x = np.random.rand(n)

# plot stuff
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax = sns.distplot(x, kde=True, hist=False, ax=ax)

# find the line and rescale y-values
children = ax.get_children()
for child in children:
    if isinstance(child, matplotlib.lines.Line2D):
        x, y = child.get_data()
        y *= n
        child.set_data(x,y)

# update y-limits (not done automatically)
ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())
fig.canvas.draw()
```

[image]